# R - Comparing 2 lists and extracting similar entries

Tags: r, list, if-statement, compare, extract

I am currently trying to compare 2 lists and pull out the entry in List2 that matches List1. Here is what I have thus far:

```
List1 <- list(1,2,3)
List2 <- list(2,4,6)
is.element(List1[2],List2)
for(i in 1:length(List1)){
  if(is.element(List1[i],List2)){
    print(List2)
  }else{

  }
}
```

At the moment when i=2 it just prints the whole of List2, which isn't what I want, can someone let me know how to extract specifically the element that matches List1[i]? 
If List1[i] doesn't match List2 I just want nothing to happen.

In the future I am planning to use this to compare a list of job titles and a list of sentences. If a job title comes up the entire sentence will be pulled out of the list of sentences. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
intersect(List1, List2)

[[1]]
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above by @Len is the best one. You actually don't need a loop here. However, so that you learn why your function didn't work. You can follow this:

```
List1 <- list(1,2,3)
List2 <- list(2,4,6)

for (i in List1){
  if (i %in% List2){
    print(i)
  }
}  

[1] 2
```